# Normalize numpy array columns in python reading that array from other csv file

Tags: python, numpy

Whenever I am trying to perform normalization over the array obtained from the csv file . My code wont work because i have n't provided the custom file.

I an getting an error message as :

```
 x = np.myarray
```

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute'myarray'**

As I am new to python ,can anyone please help me how to get a normalized matrix if we read the matrix from csv file ?

```
 import numpy as np
 import csv

 with open('csvk.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data_as_list = list(reader) 
    print data_as_list

    myarray = np.asarray(data_as_list)
    print myarray
    x = np.myarray
    x_normed = x / x.max(axis=0)
    print x_normed
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with `np.myarray`?  That is an attribute call, and Python rightly informs you that module `numpy` does not have an attribute `myarray`.  If you're just trying to make a copy of `myarray` you just want `x=myarray`, although you could do the same in a more pythonic way with `x_normed=myarray/myarray.max(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1. In general: Try to further boil down your code to the parts that will raise the Errors.
2. The community here can not run your code since you are importing a custom file. In this case the error can be seen easily but in more difficult cases you need to post code that can be executed by others also. You will get more detailed and helpful answers if your code can be run.
3. In addition to the answer of Daniel Forsman: "np.myarray" will not work and raise an Error since numpy has no attribute "myarray". If you call    python will check, if  owns the attribute . Since the module object numpy does not own an attribute myarray it will raise the AttributeError that you got.

Cheers,
Daniel